# Find All Checked Checkboxes in Backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js, coffeescript

I'm popping up a Bootstrap modal that allows users to select a number of checkboxes. Then in my View I want to loop through each and check to see if they are checked.

Here's my modal code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="ethnicityModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Ethnicity Targeting</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <h5>Select ethnicities that should be included:</h5>
        <input type="checkbox" name="caucasian"><label for="#caucasian"> Caucasian</label>
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="black"><label for="#black"> African American</label>
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="hispanic"><label for="#hispanic"> Hispanic/Latino</label>
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="middleEastern"><label for="#middleEastern"> Middle Eastern</label>
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="pacific"><label for="#pacific"> Pacific Islander</label>
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="nativeAmerican"><label for="#nativeAmerican"> Native American/Alaskan</label>
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="other"><label for="#other"> Other</label>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary saveEthnicity" data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And in my view:

```
events:
   "click .saveEthnicity": "saveEthnicity"

saveEthnicity: (e) ->
    console.log e.currentTarget.parentElement.parentNode.children[1].children
```

So the `e.currentTarget.parentElement.parentNode.children[1].children` returns me the array of children elements. But I can't seem to loop through them. I tried

```
e.currentTarget.parentElement.parentNode.children[1].children.each (child) ->
  console.log child
```

But that throws an error. Any idea how I can get to each input so I can do a `.checked()` on it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the Backbone view properly represents your modal window then you can just search for all the checked boxes with a bit of jQuery:

```
var $checkedBoxes = this.$('input:checked');
```

From the [Backbone docs](http://backbonejs.org/#View-dollar):

> Each view has a `$` function that runs queries scoped within the view's element

If the modal is not represented directly by the view then you can just search up the DOM tree until you find the nearest modal:

```
var $checkedBoxes = $(e.currentTarget).closest('modal').find('input:checked')
```

Comment: Not quite - I actually have a number of modals within that view's template and a number of them use checkboxes. So I suppose I could add a unique class to each set and maybe go from there.

Comment: @TomHammond You should definitely use something to identify which modal the button is submitting.

Comment: @TomHammond I've given you an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

The `children` property is not an array, it is an `HTMLCollection`, try this:

```
children = [].slice.apply(e.currentTarget.parentElement.parentNode.children[1].children)
children.forEach (child) -> console.log(child)
```

Comment: Ahhh, that makes a lot of sense. Thanks for the help!